# Создать форму фильтра на JS по tag для WordPress

Tags: javascript, wordpress

Кто поможет реализовать на WordPress с помощью JavaScript на сайте форму, благодаря которой возможно фильтровать и выводить статьи с теми тегами (tag), которые были выбраны в предоставленной форме.

Например, форма из двух выпадающих списков. В первом, пользователь выбрал a1, во втором d3. После, нажимает на кнопку "Ok", и переходит по адресу: site.ru/tag/a1+d3/ . В результате получается вывод всех записей, в которых присутствуют теги a1 и d3.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Пример</title>
</head>

<body>

  <form name="f1">
    <p><select name="n" id='t1'>
        <optgroup label="A">
          <option value="a1">A1</option>
          <option value="a2">A2</option>
        </optgroup>
        <optgroup label="B">
          <option value="b1">B1</option>
          <option value="b2">B2</option>
        </optgroup>
      </select>

      <select name="n1" id='t2'>
        <optgroup label="C">
          <option value="c1">C1</option>
          <option value="c2">C2</option>
          <option value="c3">C3</option>
        </optgroup>
        <optgroup label="D">
          <option value="d1">D1</option>
          <option value="d2">D2</option>
          <option value="d3">D3</option>
        </optgroup>
      </select>
    </p>
    <input type="button" onclick="f()" value="ok">
  </form>

  <script>
    function f() {
      var request = new XMLHttpRequest(); // здесь пыталась подключить "что-то"
      var a = document.getElementById('t1').value;
      var b = document.getElementById('t2').value;
      var c = a + '+' + b;

      // строка с параметрами для отправки
      request.open("GET", "https://site.ru/tag/" + c);
      request.onreadystatechange = reqReadyStateChange;
      request.send();
    }
  </script>

  <hr>

</body>

</html>
```

В приведенном коде пример того, что пыталась создать, но без навыков программирования, как говорится методом "тыка" ничего не вышло.

Comment: Незадумывалась ли ты что возможно сначяло надо было бы создать страничку со всеми этими статьями по тегам, а потом просто кликнуть и перейти по ссылке?

Comment: "надобылобы (правильно: на добыло бы) создать страничьку (правильно: страничку) с всеми (правильно: со всеми) этими стаями (а еще лучше создать домен/сайт) по тегам (перед буквой "а" ставится запятая, она выглядит вот так - ",") а потом просто кликнуть и перейти по ссылке?"

Спасибо за "полезный" комментарий, это очень мне помогло. Ещё позволь задать вопрос по теме твоего сообщения: чем отличается русский, американский и еврейский форумы?

Comment: Охо извините. У вас ссылка в ручную работает?